# How do we stop others using our licensed web-fonts?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, font-licensing

I need to use the font "Folio" on my website. I need a version of this font which I would like to store on my website so that the browser of my readers can download it and use it to render the text as designed.

I have found the font for free on a couple of websites. My question is, is it free as they say? Here is an example http://www.myfontfree.com/search.php?key=folio

Let's assume that I buy a Folio font and I use it on my site. How do I prevent others not to refer to my font in their designs?

Comment: I'm confused here.  If it's free for you to use, why do you care if anyone else uses it or where they get it from? I went to that link and, as far as I can tell, the font _is_ free.  Free for you, free for everyone.

Comment: If you want a font no one else can use, then you would need to pay a designer to make a new font that was made for you or create your own font.

Comment: I am OK with others to use it. I was not sure the font was free so I assumed that I might need to buy it but then I had the question about others using something that I paid for
It is strange that @ www.myfonts.com this font is not listed as free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Assuming you are talking about [Folio](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/folio/)—the font isn't free. A lot of "free" font sites are dubious and best avoided or at least used with caution. If you can search for the font and find it for sale, for a price, on a more reputable font site then chances are the free version is either not legitimate or a "free for personal use" demo.

---

2. If you buy a web-font license for the font you can basically use it without worrying about anyone downloading the font, that's specifically what the licence is for.

   If you are worried about people downloading the font then there are thing you can do to deter, but not much you can do to completely prevent downloads without also blocking people from viewing the font on your site!

   There is a good (although a tad old) Typekit article on the subject:
   [**Typekit Blog - Serving and Protecting Fonts on the Web**](http://blog.typekit.com/2009/07/21/serving-and-protecting-fonts-on-the-web/)

   And a related StackOverflow Q&A:
   [**How can I prevent web fonts from being downloaded and used illegally?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8907036)

Comment: How do I check if the free version is a legit version? Myfonts.com lists Folio fonts from a couple of sources but I don't see why a good Samaritan won't create a free version of this font and released to the public to use it.

Comment: The "BT" in the font name stands for Bitstream, the foundry that released that version of the font—which definitely isn't free.

Comment: There are a lot of copies of old classic fonts which may or may not be "legit" but in most cases if someone is exactly copying a font to get around licensing the original, I personally wouldn't call them a "Good Samaritan"

Comment: I am not sure I understand your logic. The font was designed in the 50s and it was given to some company to sell it legally. Today we have the font from different sources in exchange for money. So this guys copied the design of the font and they are OK but a "good Samaritan" is not good he is the evil one ?

Comment: 1. You're oversimplifying. 2. The digital versions of old fonts you use today still needed hundreds of hours of work to get them to you. 3. I said in most cases. The site you linked to is 99% fonts that *do* need licences.